# How do i delete all the lines in a file ending with colon using awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed, notepad

I have a file with some tabular data in it. But it also has some text line(ending with a colon) in between the data. So i want to remove those text lines and only have my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/:$/,""); print}' file.txt
```

This will take only the last colon and not the one which contain colon in between the line.

or as JID commented:

```
awk '!/:$/' file
```

Comment: and how do I get the output in a new file? Sorry for such silly question but i am kind of new to this.

Comment: @SiddharthKota:- `awk '{gsub(/:$/,""); print}' file.txt>output.txt`

Comment: @SiddharthKota:- You are welcome. However thats strange you marked the other answer as accepted and saying that this worked :) The point of accepting the answer is to make future readers having the same problem should get the answer which worked.

Comment: hi @RahulTripathi...i needed another small help. I want to run the above awk action on a folder containing multiple such files at once. how do I do it?

Comment: @SiddharthKota:- Could you please ask a new question for that, explaining exactly what you are looking for? That would help you as well as it will attract other people's attention as well

Answer (score 2):

you could use grep - something like

```
grep -v ":$" file
```

or sed - like

```
sed "/:$/d" file
```